# How to set up live view finder on Canon PowerShot SX240HS connected to TV screen

Tags: canon, live-view, compact-cameras

I have a Canon PowerShot SX240HS connected to a TV screen via an Ex-Pro Premium replacement for Canon HTC-100 cable (HDMI to Mini HDMI). I can playback images and video I have already taken on the TV screen but what I want is a live view finder i.e. when I am framing a shot or shooting video the camera viewfinder is displayed on the TV screen. I cant get that to work, any ideas most welcome.
Thanks,
Lee

Comment: I am also looking if it is possible to use that camera as HDMI camera.

Answer (score 1):

Page 200 of the [SX240HS/SX260HS manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/7/0300007147/01/pssx260hs-sx240hs-cug-c-en.pdf), under the section "Playback on a Standard-Definition TV" states,

> When the camera and TV are connected, you can also shoot while previewing shots on the larger screen of the TV. To shoot, follow the same steps as when using the camera screen.

It is not clear from the manual if that capability exists *only* when connected via A/V cable to standard-def TVs and not when connected via HDMI cable to HDTV.

If you have the A/V cable to connect to a standard-def TV, I would suggest  try that route and verify the live-preview capability stated in the manual.